# Multithreaded Core Data - persistentStoreCoordinator vs parentContext

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm trying to resolve issues that are being caused by accessing the same `NSManagedObjectContext` from multiple threads. I found the following in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH24-SW2):

```
let moc = … //Our primary context on the main queue

let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
privateMOC.parentContext = moc

privateMOC.performBlock {
    //...
}
```

Which seems to be what I'm after. I also found something very similar in a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113489/core-data-tutorial-multiple-managed-object-contexts#) which has been updated for iOS 9:

```
let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
privateContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coreDataStack.context.persistentStoreCoordinator

privateContext.performBlock { () -> Void in
  //...
}
```

They both seem to achieve the same, however the Apple doc's version uses `parentContext` instead of using the `persistantStoreCoordinator` directly. What is the difference between these two approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parentContext`. This is preferred to the method with the persistent store coordinator since iOS 5.

> Prior to OS X v10.7 and iOS v5.0, the parent store is always a persistent store coordinator. In OS X v10.7 and later and iOS v5.0 and later, the parent store may be another managed object context. Ultimately the root of a context’s ancestry must be a persistent store coordinator. The coordinator provides the managed object model and dispatches requests to the various persistent stores containing the data.

In your particular case:

> If a context’s parent store is another managed object context, fetch and save operations are mediated by the parent context instead of a coordinator. This pattern has a number of usage scenarios, including:
>
> - Performing background operations on a second thread or queue.

Source: NSManagedObjectContext class reference, "[Parent Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-256616)".